# Invalid column name when select column from the database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

i want to select some column from the database, but it show a error message 
Invalid column name

i double check database, i had key in correct column name, but cant select it

there are no error message pop out when i select other column

Comment: What is the specific error message? What are your column names?

Comment: It would be better if you post you sql script :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

enclose your column name in square braces `[]`. This happens in case your column name contains `special Characters, spaces, or key words`.

eg: `select [column name] from yourTable`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a query to cut an paste to find any keywords in your column names.  This is based upon http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx.  The first block is the reserved keywords in SQL Server 2012 and the second list is for the future keywords.  This will list all of the columns in your schemes that have names that may need to change.  This has been useful for a database upgrade so I wanted to share and save someone else a bit of time on finding these issues proactively.

```sql
USE [database_name]
GO

SELECT
    [S].[NAME] AS [SCHEMA],
    [O].[NAME] AS [OBJECT],
    [C].[NAME] AS [COLUMN]
FROM [SYS].[COLUMNS] AS [C]
JOIN [SYS].[OBJECTS] AS [O] ON [C].[OBJECT_ID] = [O].[OBJECT_ID]
JOIN [SYS].[SCHEMAS] AS [S] ON [O].[SCHEMA_ID] = [S].[SCHEMA_ID]
WHERE [S].[NAME] != 'sys'
AND ( 
  [C].[NAME] IN (
      'ADD', 'EXTERNAL', 'PROCEDURE', 'ALL', 'FETCH', 'PUBLIC', 'ALTER'
    , 'FILE', 'RAISERROR', 'AND', 'FILLFACTOR', 'READ', 'ANY', 'FOR'
    , 'READTEXT', 'AS', 'FOREIGN', 'RECONFIGURE', 'ASC', 'FREETEXT'
    , 'REFERENCES', 'AUTHORIZATION', 'FREETEXTTABLE', 'REPLICATION'
    , 'BACKUP', 'FROM', 'RESTORE', 'BEGIN', 'FULL', 'RESTRICT', 'BETWEEN'
    , 'FUNCTION', 'RETURN', 'BREAK', 'GOTO', 'REVERT', 'BROWSE', 'GRANT'
    , 'REVOKE', 'BULK', 'GROUP', 'RIGHT', 'BY', 'HAVING', 'ROLLBACK'
    , 'CASCADE', 'HOLDLOCK', 'ROWCOUNT', 'CASE', 'IDENTITY', 'ROWGUIDCOL'
    , 'CHECK', 'IDENTITY_INSERT', 'RULE', 'CHECKPOINT', 'IDENTITYCOL', 'SAVE'
    , 'CLOSE', 'IF', 'SCHEMA', 'CLUSTERED', 'IN', 'SECURITYAUDIT', 'COALESCE'
    , 'INDEX', 'SELECT', 'COLLATE', 'INNER', 'SEMANTICKEYPHRASETABLE', 'COLUMN'
    , 'INSERT', 'SEMANTICSIMILARITYDETAILSTABLE', 'COMMIT', 'INTERSECT'
    , 'SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE', 'COMPUTE', 'INTO', 'SESSION_USER', 'CONSTRAINT'
    , 'IS', 'SET', 'CONTAINS', 'JOIN', 'SETUSER', 'CONTAINSTABLE', 'KEY'
    , 'SHUTDOWN', 'CONTINUE', 'KILL', 'SOME', 'CONVERT', 'LEFT', 'STATISTICS'
    , 'CREATE', 'LIKE', 'SYSTEM_USER', 'CROSS', 'LINENO', 'TABLE', 'CURRENT'
    , 'LOAD', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'CURRENT_DATE', 'MERGE', 'TEXTSIZE', 'CURRENT_TIME'
    , 'NATIONAL', 'THEN', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'NOCHECK', 'TO', 'CURRENT_USER'
    , 'NONCLUSTERED', 'TOP', 'CURSOR', 'NOT', 'TRAN', 'DATABASE', 'NULL'
    , 'TRANSACTION', 'DBCC', 'NULLIF', 'TRIGGER', 'DEALLOCATE', 'OF', 'TRUNCATE'
    , 'DECLARE', 'OFF', 'TRY_CONVERT', 'DEFAULT', 'OFFSETS', 'TSEQUAL', 'DELETE'
    , 'ON', 'UNION', 'DENY', 'OPEN', 'UNIQUE', 'DESC', 'OPENDATASOURCE'
    , 'UNPIVOT', 'DISK', 'OPENQUERY', 'UPDATE', 'DISTINCT', 'OPENROWSET'
    , 'UPDATETEXT', 'DISTRIBUTED', 'OPENXML', 'USE', 'DOUBLE', 'OPTION', 'USER'
    , 'DROP', 'OR', 'VALUES', 'DUMP', 'ORDER', 'VARYING', 'ELSE', 'OUTER'
    , 'VIEW', 'END', 'OVER', 'WAITFOR', 'ERRLVL', 'PERCENT', 'WHEN', 'ESCAPE'
    , 'PIVOT', 'WHERE', 'EXCEPT', 'PLAN', 'WHILE', 'EXEC', 'PRECISION', 'WITH'
    , 'EXECUTE', 'PRIMARY', 'WITHIN GROUP', 'EXISTS', 'PRINT', 'WRITETEXT'
    , 'EXIT', 'PROC'
  )
  OR [C].[NAME] IN (
    'ABSOLUTE', 'HOST', 'RELATIVE', 'ACTION', 'HOUR', 'RELEASE'
  , 'ADMIN', 'IGNORE', 'RESULT', 'AFTER', 'IMMEDIATE', 'RETURNS', 'AGGREGATE'
  , 'INDICATOR', 'ROLE', 'ALIAS', 'INITIALIZE', 'ROLLUP', 'ALLOCATE', 'INITIALLY'
  , 'ROUTINE', 'ARE', 'INOUT', 'ROW', 'ARRAY', 'INPUT', 'ROWS', 'ASENSITIVE'
  , 'INT', 'SAVEPOINT', 'ASSERTION', 'INTEGER', 'SCROLL', 'ASYMMETRIC'
  , 'INTERSECTION', 'SCOPE', 'AT', 'INTERVAL', 'SEARCH', 'ATOMIC', 'ISOLATION'
  , 'SECOND', 'BEFORE', 'ITERATE', 'SECTION', 'BINARY', 'LANGUAGE', 'SENSITIVE'
  , 'BIT', 'LARGE', 'SEQUENCE', 'BLOB', 'LAST', 'SESSION', 'BOOLEAN', 'LATERAL'
  , 'SETS', 'BOTH', 'LEADING', 'SIMILAR', 'BREADTH', 'LESS', 'SIZE', 'CALL'
  , 'LEVEL', 'SMALLINT', 'CALLED', 'LIKE_REGEX', 'SPACE', 'CARDINALITY', 'LIMIT'
  , 'SPECIFIC', 'CASCADED', 'LN', 'SPECIFICTYPE', 'CAST', 'LOCAL', 'SQL'
  , 'CATALOG', 'LOCALTIME', 'SQLEXCEPTION', 'CHAR', 'LOCALTIMESTAMP', 'SQLSTATE'
  , 'CHARACTER', 'LOCATOR', 'SQLWARNING', 'CLASS', 'MAP', 'START', 'CLOB'
  , 'MATCH', 'STATE', 'COLLATION', 'MEMBER', 'STATEMENT', 'COLLECT', 'METHOD'
  , 'STATIC', 'COMPLETION', 'MINUTE', 'STDDEV_POP', 'CONDITION', 'MOD'
  , 'STDDEV_SAMP', 'CONNECT', 'MODIFIES', 'STRUCTURE', 'CONNECTION', 'MODIFY'
  , 'SUBMULTISET', 'CONSTRAINTS', 'MODULE', 'SUBSTRING_REGEX', 'CONSTRUCTOR'
  , 'MONTH', 'SYMMETRIC', 'CORR', 'MULTISET', 'SYSTEM', 'CORRESPONDING'
  , 'NAMES', 'TEMPORARY', 'COVAR_POP', 'NATURAL', 'TERMINATE', 'COVAR_SAMP'
  , 'NCHAR', 'THAN', 'CUBE', 'NCLOB', 'TIME', 'CUME_DIST', 'NEW', 'TIMESTAMP'
  , 'CURRENT_CATALOG', 'NEXT', 'TIMEZONE_HOUR', 'CURRENT_DEFAULT_TRANSFORM_GROUP'
  , 'NO', 'TIMEZONE_MINUTE', 'CURRENT_PATH', 'NONE', 'TRAILING', 'CURRENT_ROLE'
  , 'NORMALIZE', 'TRANSLATE_REGEX', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA', 'NUMERIC', 'TRANSLATION'
  , 'CURRENT_TRANSFORM_GROUP_FOR_TYPE', 'OBJECT', 'TREAT', 'CYCLE'
  , 'OCCURRENCES_REGEX', 'TRUE', 'DATA', 'OLD', 'UESCAPE', 'DATE', 'ONLY'
  , 'UNDER', 'DAY', 'OPERATION', 'UNKNOWN', 'DEC', 'ORDINALITY', 'UNNEST'
  , 'DECIMAL', 'OUT', 'USAGE', 'DEFERRABLE', 'OVERLAY', 'USING', 'DEFERRED'
  , 'OUTPUT', 'VALUE', 'DEPTH', 'PAD', 'VAR_POP', 'DEREF', 'PARAMETER'
  , 'VAR_SAMP', 'DESCRIBE', 'PARAMETERS', 'VARCHAR', 'DESCRIPTOR', 'PARTIAL'
  , 'VARIABLE', 'DESTROY', 'PARTITION', 'WHENEVER', 'DESTRUCTOR', 'PATH'
  , 'WIDTH_BUCKET', 'DETERMINISTIC', 'POSTFIX', 'WITHOUT', 'DICTIONARY'
  , 'PREFIX', 'WINDOW', 'DIAGNOSTICS', 'PREORDER', 'WITHIN', 'DISCONNECT'
  , 'PREPARE', 'WORK', 'DOMAIN', 'PERCENT_RANK', 'WRITE', 'DYNAMIC'
  , 'PERCENTILE_CONT', 'XMLAGG', 'EACH', 'PERCENTILE_DISC', 'XMLATTRIBUTES'
  , 'ELEMENT', 'POSITION_REGEX', 'XMLBINARY', 'END-EXEC', 'PRESERVE'
  , 'XMLCAST', 'EQUALS', 'PRIOR', 'XMLCOMMENT', 'EVERY', 'PRIVILEGES'
  , 'XMLCONCAT', 'EXCEPTION', 'RANGE', 'XMLDOCUMENT', 'FALSE', 'READS'
  , 'XMLELEMENT', 'FILTER', 'REAL', 'XMLEXISTS', 'FIRST', 'RECURSIVE'
  , 'XMLFOREST', 'FLOAT', 'REF', 'XMLITERATE', 'FOUND', 'REFERENCING'
  , 'XMLNAMESPACES', 'FREE', 'REGR_AVGX', 'XMLPARSE', 'FULLTEXTTABLE', 'REGR_AVGY'
  , 'XMLPI', 'FUSION', 'REGR_COUNT', 'XMLQUERY', 'GENERAL', 'REGR_INTERCEPT'
  , 'XMLSERIALIZE', 'GET', 'REGR_R2', 'XMLTABLE', 'GLOBAL', 'REGR_SLOPE'
  , 'XMLTEXT', 'GO', 'REGR_SXX', 'XMLVALIDATE', 'GROUPING', 'REGR_SXY'
  , 'YEAR', 'HOLD', 'REGR_SYY', 'ZONE'
  )
)

GO
```